# C's regexec matches '1111111' to '^[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}$'

Tags: c, regex

The following code is what I've written as a standalone test for a part of a larger project I'm working on; it's supposed to detect IPv4 addresses in quartet form (four up-to-three-digit numbers separated by periods):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv []) {
   regex_t regex;
    int ret;
    char * reg = "^[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}$";

    ret = regcomp(& regex, reg, REG_NEWLINE | REG_EXTENDED);
    if (ret) {
            printf("no compile\n");
    } else {
            printf("compile\n");
    }

    char ips [17];
    fgets(ips, 17, stdin);

    ret = regexec(& regex, ips, 0, NULL, 0);

    if (! ret) {
            printf("match\n");
    } else {
            printf("no match\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I type in '1111111' and hit enter, it prints 'y'. This does not seem right.

```
$ [name of compiled file]
comp
11111111
y
$
```

It also matches longer strings of ones; I haven't gone past ten.

Comment: What do you think a backslash does in a C string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an escaping problem:

```
"^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}$"
```

At the moment you escape your dot once, which makes them dots (the regex dots kind). Also, you shouldn't need to escape the curly braces.

Comment: You still missed escaping the first `.`